# SSRS OraOLEDB.Oracle provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017

I have been trying to create a Data source in SSRS to the oracle DB. I have already installed Oracle 12.1.0, updated the windows environment variable to the oracle folder and registered the regsvr32.exe to the OraOledb12.dll.

I have also restarted my system several times. I am still getting the error below. Can somebody please help me in that.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I had to install Oracle 11 Client_32. Also cross check the environment variables. It worked after that